# Question about Griffiths' proof that $\Psi$ stays normalized

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

In "Introducion to Quantum Mechanixs", at p. 16, Griffiths writes what follows:[image]

Now, if $\Psi$ is just assumed to be in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, this does not imply that $|\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}|$ is bounded for $x\to\infty$, so along particular sequences $x_n\to\infty$ the limit of $\Psi \frac{\partial\Psi^*}{\partial x}$ or $\Psi^* \frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}$ could be different from $0$ or even diverge.

How can one fix this?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/519341/

Comment: In fact the claim about the behaviour at infinity is simply false without assuming some further hypotheses on $\psi$. The statement about the fact that the $t$ derivative is zero is however true **without any further hypoteses than $\psi \in L^2$**. It is just the general framework which is quite meaningless, mathematically speaking. You have to choose between the correct mathematical reason or some heuristic physical motivations.

Comment: @ValterMoretti So can you please elaborate on why the time derivative is zero assuming just $\Psi\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 I really liked the answers to the question you linked, especially the one concerning the domain of unbounded operators. Thanks.

Comment: @Uagi I posted my answer below.

Comment: @ValterMoretti Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proof by Griffiths relies in fact on stronger (implicit) hypotheses about the behaviour of $\psi$ at infinity. These hypotheses could be justified by requiring (as in Giorgio's answer of the other question) that the used $\psi$ also belongs to the domains of some observables (selfadjoint operators): Nevertheless the main claim is valid  even if $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ without further restrictions.

The general validity is due to the fact that time evolution, due to basic axioms of QM, is given by an one-parameter group of unitary operators.

The Schroedinger equation
$$i\hbar \frac{d}{dt} \psi_t = H\psi_t$$
makes sense only if $\psi \in D(H)$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian observable.
Its domain $D(H)$ is a dense subspace of the Hilbert space. However the map which associates the solution at time $t$ (in $D(H)$) with the initial condition in $D(H)$:
$$U_t : D(H) \ni \psi_0 \mapsto \psi \in D(H)$$
is $L^2(\mathbb{R})$-continuous: that is because it can be written in terms of a unitary map as I explain below. Therefore, as $D(H)$ is dense, continuously extends to the whole Hilbert space
$$U_t  : L^2(\mathbb{R}) \to L^2(\mathbb{R}).$$
More explicitly, as $H$ is selfadjoint, we can take advantage of the functional calculus and the operator $U_t$ can be written as  $U_t= e^{-i t H/ \hbar}$. Here selfadjointness of $H$ implies unitarity of $U_t$:
$$U_t^\dagger = (e^{-i t H/ \hbar})^\dagger = e^{+i t H^\dagger \! / \hbar}= e^{i t H/ \hbar}= U_t^{-1}\:.$$
In particular,
$$U^\dagger U = e^{i t H/ \hbar} e^{-i t H/ \hbar} = e^{-i (t-t) H/ \hbar}= e^{i 0 H/ \hbar}= I\:.$$
As a consequence, if $\psi \in L^2({\mathbb{R}})$
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |\psi(x,t)|^2 dx = ||U_t \psi_0||^2=\langle U_t \psi_0| U_t \psi_0\rangle = \langle \psi_0| U^\dagger_tU_t  \psi_0\rangle= \langle \psi_0|\psi_0\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}}  |\psi(x,0)|^2 dx\:.$$